# UI Automation fails with pywinauto ElementNotFoundError when there is no Windows Software Development Kit installed

Tags: python, automation, powerbi, ui-automation, pywinauto

I am using pywinauto python library for UI automation. This Python script I created could detect the Power BI Desktop app elements I needed to automate before. However, when the Power BI app was upgraded to its latest version, the script fails to detect the app elements if Windows SDK (Windows Software Development Kit) is not installed.

The error I encounter now is below if I do not install Windows Software Development Kit (Windows SDK that is about 800+MB in disk size). This does not happen before even if no Windows SDK is installed (Version of Power BI where this script works was 2.72.5556.801). With the latest version of Power BI (2.81.5831.821), this error happens:

```
pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'title': 'Save', 'control_type': 'Button', 'top_level_only': False, 'parent': <uia_element_info.UIAElementInfo - 'DashBoardFile - Power BI Desktop', Wind
owsForms10.Window.8.app.0.2562bc8_r30_ad1, 1312804>, 'backend': 'uia'}
None
```

The script/code snippet I used is below:

```
# Connect pywinauto
log.info(LOG_PBIX + "Identifying Power BI window")
app = Application(backend='uia').connect(path="PBIDesktop.exe")
win = app.window(title_re='.*Power BI Desktop')

time.sleep(5)
win.wait("enabled", timeout=300)

# Set mouse focus to Power BI window
win.set_focus()
log.info(LOG_PBIX + "Power BI Window focused.")

# Get "Save" button
saveObj = win.child_window(title="Save", control_type="Button")
saveObj.click_input()
```

The Windows SDK which I installed is from this link: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive/
I only installed Windows Software Development Kit from this SDK since I have been using Inspect.exe to guide me in coding the UI automation with pywinauto.

What is in Windows Software Development Kit that makes pywinauto work? I hope someone could enlighten me on this. Or, any feedback on this matter will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This is question for Power BI developers how they use specific Windows SDK version.

Comment: Hi @Vasily Ryabov, you are right. I also posted the same/similar question to pywinauto github (https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/943) but no response yet. Apparently, when Inspect.exe is run (included in Windows SDK that I installed), the Power BI elements are exposed, then pywinauto can also detect the Power BI elements thereafter.

Comment: It’s worth to ask PowerBI developers, not us. Pywinauto can do nothing with bad testability support inside the app. I’m pywinauto maintainer. There is no much sense submitting such issues on pywinauto.